# I have the iphone 4s and it will not record videos

Tags: iphone

My iphone 4s will not let me take pictures or videos it keeps telling me that i do not have enough space available. But i have recently taken all my picture off and put them on my computer. So i have very few picture on the iphone and very few apps. I have tried deleting both more apps and picture but it does not seem to help. What is going on? this has never happened before what should i do? Thank you! :)

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? (Settings > General > About) Also, check your available space. (Settings > General > Usage) Just because you synced your photos with the computer does not necessarily mean they were removed from the device.

Comment: Also have you restarted the phone?

Comment: I have tried restarting several times.  :( Also i checked the version and it says 8.0.2 (12A405) I synced the pictures and deleted them from my phone. They can no longer be found anywhere on the phone. @tubedogg

Comment: What does it say for usage?

Comment: It doesnt seem to matter how much i delete or restart it still does not show i have more room... @Tyson

Comment: used says 12.7 and avalable says 0 even though i have deleted more apps and videos and photos. :/ @tubedogg

Comment: I fee like something i dont know about must be taking up a lot of space... I used to have WAY more photos and videos on the phone and it was fine.It is a 16GB and i know the programs take up some space to run the  phone but 3.3GB? thats a bit much wouldnt you say? @tubedogg

Comment: Plug it into the computer and use iTunes to look at the available space. Along the bottom it has a bar chart showing the categories of things that are using space. This may help you determine what is there.

Comment: Good idea I will try that. :) I wish i could send you screen shots so you could see easier what i see! @tubedogg

Comment: alright i see that Documents and Data are taking up space and i dont know what that exactly represents...? The rest make sense small music section, photos med, apps small and med D & D .@tubedogg

Answer (score 1):

Go to your settings, press general, then usage. See how much space you have left. There may be something else taking up your space.

Comment: it says i have 0 space. :( and 12.7 is taken.

Comment: This is the problem. You need to delete some stuff. You only get 12.7 because some goes to formatting, iOS, etc. You should then be able to take videos. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your Photo Stream if that is on.

- Open Settings and go to “Photos & Camera”
- Toggle “My Photo Stream” to the OFF position

That will free up about 1+ GB of storage.

Comment: Really? I am trying that now and it says "turning off photo stream will delete all photo stream photos from your iphone" what does that mean? before i do it i want to make sure it will not delete all my pictures! :/ @profFrnswrth

Comment: @Rayne the statement _before i do it i want to make sure it will not delete all my pictures!_ and this statement from the question _But i have recently taken all my picture off and put them on my computer._ don't seem to support each others validity.

Comment: Photo Stream photos are seperate from your Camera Roll photos. Turning off Photo Stream will not delete all the photos from your phone. Just Photo Stream.

Comment: I have taken MORE photos since removing old photos. Recently does not mean 10 min ago to me. It means a week or two in this case. @Tyson

Comment: If you read my question properly in the first place you see that i stated i had some photos on my phone currently. @Tyson

Comment: yea I read the questions properly you can't take pictures or videos... but now you state you can, so whatever. I'll go I'm done here

Answer (score 0):

I still am not entirely sure why I only have 12.7 space on my 16 GB iphone; however i deleted my last iphone update and was then able to take pictures and videos once again.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS operating system software built into the phone consumes more than 3gb of your overall storage space, which started at 16gb before apple loaded the iOS operating system on your phone.